# how to pass null in date column using storedprocedure in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have date column where if it is null then it doesn't insert any value further.

In Database getting error CALL

```
return_ship_stones("1.01","IF",
         "G", "EC/0122/19-20", "", "2", 
        "5.44x5.23x3.92" , "3822" , "1333041478" , "1" ,
         "1333041478" , "Princess" , "3860.2200000000003", "", "125")   

Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '' for column ``.``.`_invoicedate` at row 5 0.000 sec

$updstmt = '';

      foreach ($StoneArr as $Stone)
      {
        $textboxval = $_REQUEST['textboxval'];
        $refVal = $textboxval;
        $clientname = $_REQUEST['clientname'];

         $updstmt .= 'CALL return_ship_stones('.'"'.$Stone["carat"].'"'.','.'"'.$Stone["clarity"].'"'.',
        '.'"'.$Stone["color"].'"'.', '.'"'.$Stone["invcno"].'"'.', '.'"'.$StoneArr["invoicedate"].'"'.', '.'"'.$Stone["lab"].'"'.', 
       '.'"'.$Stone["measurement"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["ppt"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["qstonesid"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["qty"].'"'.' ,
        '.'"'.$Stone["reportno"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["shape"].'"'.' , '.'"'.$Stone["totalvalue"].'"'.', '.'"'.$refVal.'"'.', '.'"'.$clientname.'"'.');';
      }
```

I am expecting if it is null then date column should take null or default value like "0000-00-00".

Comment: add `coalesce('"'.$StoneArr["invoicedate"].'"', '0000-00-00')`

Comment: Use prepared statements with bind variables.

Comment: that is some crazy code right there...

Comment: $StoneArr["invoicedate"] is empty and your routine expects a date valid date and 0000-00-00 isn't a date. Try To send instead NULL or a date like 1970-01-02, for which you can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally untested but perhaps you would find the following simpler and more robust. If you use a `prepared statement` you can use the same statement for multiple executions by assigning new values to the `bound` variables. This not only makes your code much easier to read and debug but is faster ( marginal perhaps ) and mitigates the dangers SQL injection.

```
$sql='call `return_ship_stones`(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
$stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

if( $stmt ){

    $refVal=$_REQUEST['textboxval'];
    $clientname = $_REQUEST['clientname'];  

    /* 15 type placeholders must match 15 variables ... */
    $stmt->bind_param( 'sssssssssssssss', $carat, $clarity, $color, $invcno, $invoicedate, $lab, $measurement, $ppt, $qstonesid, $qty, $reportno, $shape, $totalvalue, $refVal, $clientname );

    /*
        iterate through your array and assign a value 
        to the above variables prior to executing the 
        statement.

        Was the use of `$StoneArr['invoicedate']` in 
        the loop rather than `$Stone['invoicedate']`
        correct?
    */
    foreach( $StoneArr as $Stone ){
        $carat=$Stone['carat'];
        $clarity=$Stone['clarity'];
        $color=$Stone['color'];
        $invcno=$Stone['invcno'];
        $invoicedate=!empty( $Stone['invoicedate'] ) ? $Stone['invoicedate'] : '0000-00-00';
        $lab=$Stone['lab'];
        $measurement=$Stone['measurement'];
        $ppt=$Stone['ppt'];
        $qstonesid=$Stone['qstonesid'];
        $qty=$Stone['qty'];
        $reportno=$Stone['reportno'];
        $shape=$Stone['shape'];
        $totalvalue=$Stone['totalvalue'];

        $result = $stmt->execute();
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $db->close();

} else {
    exit( 'Failed to prepare SQL query' );
}
```